# Pause and resume download in web application flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, download

I am going to implement functionality of downloading big files in web application. 
I am using flex and .net for that. From flex request for url and .net will send download url. Then it will start download the file.

The process is when user click on download button then open new window and start download with progress bar. 
 There is also pause button to pause download and if any problem with connection then pause download and again connection reset then start download again from same place from where download pause.

**My question:**
Is it possible what i am going to do with flex. Is pause and resume download with progress bar possible with web application in flex? 
 If yes then how?
 If no then what is the another options for that?

Currently i am going to download file using `FileReference.save()`  method. but, as per my knowledge it is not possible to pause with `FileReference`.

Your every help will appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resumable Downloads can be implemented via [HTTP 1.1 Range Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233).

Due to security restrictions the "range" header is not allowed in [URLRequestHeader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html) together with Flash Player, but here is an [example of how to use it in AIR](http://mariusht.com/blog/2010/03/10/resumable-file-downloader-simple-air-app/).

Comment: yes i show that example of AIR. But currently i  am making web application. In which there is video file of more than 1 GB. So, for that i need to use resumable downloads.